# Determinant of Jacobian of the transformation from cartesian to polar

Tags: polar-coordinates, jacobian, change-of-variable

I'm reading a textbook on numerical methods and it claims with no proof that the determinant of the matrix given by

\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\;\;\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\\ \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\;\;\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix}

is 2, (here $r=x^2+y^2$). I tried to verify it using the formulas for the derivative of arcsine and arccosine and I get the determinant as 4. Am I wrong or is the textbook wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall from your trig calculus identities: $~\frac{\mathrm d \arctan u}{\mathrm d u} = (1+u^2)^{-1}$

Assuming $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta=\arctan(y/x)$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\\ \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x\,(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2} & y\,(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}\\[1ex] -y\,(x^2+y^2)^{-1}& x\,(x^2+y^2)^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So the determinant is $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

---

After the edit:

> here $r=x^2+y^2$

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\\ \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2x & 2y\\[1ex] -y\,(x^2+y^2)^{-1}& x\,(x^2+y^2)^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

So the determinant is $2$

Comment: So they should.  @Bye_World

Comment: Sorry, I messed up. $r=x^2+y^2$

Comment: Yes, that makes a difference.

Comment: I understand now. It seems that one should write theta in terms of x and y and then differentiate to get the second row of the matrix. Why is it wrong to write theta as an arcsine function of x and r and then differentiate with respect to x. That approach gives me 2x/x+2y/y=4

Comment: Well, you could write $\theta=\arccos(\frac{x}{\sqrt{r}})$ (with notes about the quadrant) then take the partial with respect to $x$, applying the chain rule.  But it's messy and in the end you'll need to write in terms of $x,y$ anyway; so its simpler to do so from the beginning.

Comment: When $x>0, y>0$ $\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial \arccos(x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2})}{\partial x\qquad\qquad\qquad}~=~&\dfrac{-\frac{\partial (x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2})}{\partial x\qquad}}{\sqrt{1-x^2/(x^2+y^2)}\;}\\[1ex]~=~&\dfrac{-\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)~}~\frac{\partial (x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2})}{\partial x\qquad}}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)-x^2}\;}\\[1ex]~=~&\dfrac{-\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)~}~\frac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)-x^2}\;}\\[1ex]~=~&-\frac{y}{(x^2+y^2)}\\[2ex]\dfrac{\partial\arcsin(y/\sqrt(x^2+y^2))}{\partial y}~=~&\dfrac{x}{(x^2+y^2)}\end{align}$